# Upgrade to 3.1.1 Fails

Tags: customization, upgrade

When doing an automatic upgrade, I get this:

Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.1.1.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Could not create directory.: /public_html

Installation Failed

All my wp files are in /public_html and the directory already exists. The FTP user I am logging in as owns all the Wordpress files, so it cannot be a chmod problem. Is there any reason why this error is occurring?

Comment: Where are you unpacking the zip file?  On your server directly?  Are you exporting the files to a directory that does not exist? Please tell us more about your process.

Comment: I am using the Automatic Upgrade feature in wp-admin. I have done dozens of upgrades like this before with no problem. It's this one installation that is causing problems.

Comment: Are you on a shared host or your own server?  Could file permissions have changed outside of your control?

Comment: No, I have a dedicated server. All files are owned by the FTP user I am using.

Comment: I am at a loss, however I found this support article: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/30-upgrade-bug-ftps I suspect that you have already tried some of their suggestions?

Comment: This is a question far better-suited to an IRC session or the WP.org support forums, in my opinion. There's too much back-and-forth necessary in diagnosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and the answer was found (a) in enabling ftp to write and (b) at least temporarily setting the directories to 777 although I think the latter permissions can be improved.

I run vsftp with chroot'd users.  After finding no mention in apache logs, setting the permissions to 777, changing ftp group to www-data, enabling anonymous ftp to write, tearing my hair out, kicking the dog etc etc the penny eventually dropped that ftp was not allowed to write.  I also upgraded a multi-site to 3.1.1 and that needs 777 set (well probably less) but returns the files 640.

It may be that a changed ftp configuration has tripped you up.

Answer (score 0):

The codex mentions:

> Note that your files all need to be owned by the user under which your Apache server executes.

and

> Automatic update has been known to fail if you're not using PHP5.

Codex: [Automatic_Update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Update)

Additional, I found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/30-upgrade-bug-ftps) Wordpress Support article featuring a similar problem for 3.x upgrades.

Comment: Yes, I have both of those. I have done automatic updates many times before. Only this particular one is failing.